# How can I get a thumbnail from a video that a user has uploaded to my server?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails, jwplayer

I'm working on a video sharing website where people can upload their own videos and I want the most recent uploads to be shown on the index page, but not as videos but **thumbnails**, so that when you click on the thumbnail you get to the video page. You guys all know how youtube's index looks/works -- that's what I'm trying to simulate. 
I read about ffmpeg but it seems to me it would only work if you have ffmpeg installed on your computer. I want this to be an automated process though without the user having to first install something on their pc. 
Is there a way I can code this? Or do i have to use some kind of framework or CMS? Could this problem be solved by simply getting ffmpeg hosting ([example](http://www.arvixe.com/ffmpeg_ffmpeg-php_hosting))?
If there is no manual way to do this in php, is there way using python?
Fyi, my website is written in php and i use jwplayer to stream the videos. 
Please note that I want to get a thumbnail from a video that's been uploaded on my server and not a youtube or vimeo thumbnail.

Comment: Seems to me like you have misunderstood something. ffmpeg needs to be installed on the server where the videos are uploaded to. When the user uploads a video you probably create an entry in a database and move the file somewhere. During this process you would also call ffmpeg to create a thumbnail for the video, no need for the user to have anything installed.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Is it possible to install ffmpeg on a shared hosting server?

Comment: That entirely depends on the provider, but i would not count on it unless its something the specifically provide.

Comment: A lot of shared hosts don't allow for it.

Comment: You could simply [download a static binary of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) (no need to install).

Comment: How does the static binary work?

Answer (score 4):

I have worked on this kind of issue and I am sure that user don't need ffmpeg on there pc instead you need a server which has ffmpeg installed.

To create thumbnail from video try the code below.

```
<?php
 $video = 'path/to/video.flv';
 $thumbnail = 'path/to/thumbnail.jpg';
 shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $thumbnail 2>&1");
 ?>
```

Comment: If you want to seek into the video stream instead of grabbing the first "second", just add `-ss 00:10:00.1` (for instance) before the `-i` option.